# How to Hide/Disable Content in HTML

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, jsp

This is my site [mycareerpath.co.in](http://mycareerpath.co.in). In that How can I delete "FREE DOMAIN + 1GB HOSTING" from my site

### Note

please right click and see the view source.

Comment: My god, why are you using inline styles?

Comment: When should it be hided? on a click? on page load? are there other font elements? if you post more code you will get better answers

Comment: @Magnet, because he might not know better, care to teach him instead of pointing badpractise error on his code?

Comment: "without affecting the tags", what **can** you do to the code?

Comment: @Magnet better: my god, why are you still using `<font>` ?

Comment: Well, that may be true, but he may be in a situation where using CSS may not be practical. I don't know. But judging by the fact he's using `<font>` I'd say he doesn't know any better. My point is, it never hurts to ask :)

Comment: Why send the content at all if you don't want people to see it?

Comment: @Anigel: I think he gets it from his hoster and doesn't want to pay to disable it.

Answer (score 2):

By far simplest and will work in all browsers, use HTML comments:

```
<!-- 

<font style="TOP: 0%; LEFT: 0%; VISIBILITY: visible; POSITION: absolute;background-color:#ffffff; z-index:111">&nbsp;
<a style="font-family:arial;font-size:12px;text-decoration: none; color: #0000FF;" href="http://hosting.India.to"> Domain Name + 
1GB Linux India Web Hosting in Rs.349 </a><font size="4"> &nbsp; </font><br>
</font>

-->
```

Answer (score 1):

add id to you anchor and use id selector..

```
$('#anchorId').hide(); //to hide

 $('#anchorId').click(function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
 }); //to disable the link.
```

or with CSS

```
 #anchorId{
   display:none;
 }; //to hide
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`hide()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) function in jquery

Example:-

```
<a href='test.html' id='link'>hello</a>
$('#link').hide();
```

Comment: I am just wondering if `display:none` wouldn't do what he wants?? I may be wrong. Please correct me if I am wrong

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot comment your code, you can add a onpageload attr to body and call a javascript function to not display the anchor tag.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function Hide() {
    document.getElementById('Id_of_anchor_tag').style.display = "none";

}
</script>
```

Comment: put the anchor tag inside a div tag and call the above javascript function using onpageload and use the id of div tag inside javascript.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".messages").fadeOut('slow');
});
</script>

<font style="TOP: 0%; LEFT: 0%; VISIBILITY: visible; POSITION: absolute;background-color:#ffffff; z-index:111">&nbsp;
<div class="messages">
<a style="font-family:arial;font-size:12px;text-decoration: none; color: #0000FF;" href="#">welcome</a><font size="4"> &nbsp; </font><br>
</font></div>
```

This will not only remove link but will display an message WELCOME which will fade and disappear automatically .

Answer (score 0):

Use following code to hide the anchor. Note, this will only hide the anchor inside the font tag and nothing else.

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $("font a").hide();
});
```

EDIT:
To hide very specific anchor inside `font` tag, which contain certain URL, use following code -

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $("font a").each(function() {
        if($(this).attr("href") == "http://hosting.India.to") {
            $(this).hide();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: doesn't it hide **all** anchors inside **all** font tags?

Comment: Updated my answer. Now it'll hide only specific tag.

Comment: This is my site mycareerpath.co.in. In that how can i delete "FREE DOMAIN + 1GB HOSTING" from my site 

Note
please right click and see the view source.

Comment: This illegal if you haven't paid for hosting and want to get rid of the advertisement. But if you've paid for it and still getting these ads, then it's unethical on your hosting provider part to put the ads.
Ideally, there should be some option which will turn off these **promotions**. Try finding those.

If you don't get those options then try following code, it will work in your case as I've already tested with your website itself.

`$("font a").each(function() {
    if($(this).attr("href") == "http://hosting.India.to") {
        $(this).parent().hide();
    }
});`